# "Cannot load such file -- openssl" when running bundle

Tags: packaging, ruby

When I try to use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/), I get the error:

> /home/vivek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)

The complete error message is below. How do I fix this?

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Please include the full output of the command, your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. Thanks!
/home/vivek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:447:in `ssl'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:216:in `connection_for'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:135:in `fetch'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:163:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:122:in `fetch_remote_specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:205:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `each'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:202:in `block in index'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:198:in `index'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48:in `run'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 10):

The following tutorial recommends recompiling Ruby with SSL support: http://www.dinduks.com/rails-cannot-load-such-file-openssl

Assuming that you use RVM, these are the steps to follow to fix this issue.

Install the openssl package

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Remove the Ruby installation you're using

```
rvm remove 1.9.3
```

And finally recompile Ruby with openssl

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Everything should be working now. Don't forget to:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Here are some more links which basically suggest to do the same:

- https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1776
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642368/why-require-mongo-gives-me-loaderror-no-such-file-to-load-openssl
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845953/how-to-install-a-rails-application-when-using-rvm
- http://www.beginnerruby.com/rails-troubleshooting/fixing-opensslbundler-issue-for-rails-on-debian/

Comment: For the records, your method worked for me. My install requires RVM to be installed for all users, so the OpenSSL directory is /usr/local/rvm/usr. Thank you for the detailed explanation, and for the extra links. You deserve the good answer mark > @Vivek